# how can I acces a service that is synthetic?

Tags: symfony-3.3

I'm new to symfony, how can I acces a service that is synthetic? I've tried with code below apprently service doesn't exist:

Symfony3.

## service.yml

```
app_coder:
  my_provider:
    acme:
      factory: factory_path
  synthetic : true
  public: true
```

## controller

```
$this->container->get('app_coder.my_provider.acme')
```

sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using synthetic service, you should first set the service instance into the container as it is stated in [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/synthetic_services.html).
To make things more flexible, you may first check if instance already exists and set if not. So something like this may help you:

```
if ($container->hasDefinition('app_coder.my_provider')) {
    $container->set('app_coder.my_provider', new MyProviderService());
}
```

And after it was setted, you may get it:

```
$this->container->get('app_coder.my_provider')
```